# ActiveMq C++ client install says APR is not installed, why?

Tags: c++, c, linux, installation, activemq-classic

I m trying to install ActiveMQ C++ client install (CMS)

I am getting the following error, when i try to configure.

```
configure: WARNING: APR not found
The Apache Portable Runtime (APR) library cannot be found.
Please install APR on this system and supply the appropriate
--with-apr option to 'configure'
configure: error: no suitable APR found
```

I do have apr and apr-util install as follows:

```
~/activemq-cpp-library-3.3.0 $ rpm -qa|grep apr
apr-1.2.7-11.el5_6.5
apr-devel-1.2.7-11.el5_6.5
apr-1.2.7-11.el5_6.5
apr-util-1.2.7-11.el5_5.2
xorg-x11-drv-dynapro-1.1.0-2
apr-util-1.2.7-11.el5_5.2
apr-devel-1.2.7-11.el5_6.5
```

Well i can add the prefix --with-apr to configure it but i dont know the path.

When i do

```
$ locate apr | less
```

It greps everything that has apr in it.

How can i resolve this?

Comment: On debian-derived systems you usually also need the `-dev` package to get headers and so on. Looking at http://www.apache.org/dist/apr/binaries/rpm/i386/ it seems like it could be `-devel` for red hat based systems.

Comment: i do have apr-devel installed. see edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveMQ-CPP requires APR and APR-Util version 1.3 or higher, you can find these listed in the README file along with the other required dependencies.

Comment: yeah so i had to manually download the apr-1-4-5 and apr-util, install them and install the c++ libraries with this versions. it was a painful process.